# MSVC9: How do I view a location in memory?

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, visual-c++

I'm pretty sure I'm  overlooking something totally obvious, but I want to view the raw contents of a point in memory under MSVC9, but I can't find a location in the UI where I can punch in a memory address. How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple of places:

1. When you're debugging, go to Debug->Windows->Memory
2. In the watch window, just cast a memory address to whatever you want:

   ```
   (char*)0xdeadbeef
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Also check out the [format specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt.aspx) for use in the watch window.  My favourites are `hr` and `wm` but you should check out `m` and its friends.